# What is the path toward root node in the tree?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, pattern-matching

Suppose we have a tree. The special property about this tree is that it's properly numbered but in a unique fashion. The root of the tree has number 1 associated with it followed by 2 children which are numbered 2 and 3 respectively. Then 2 has 3 children namely 4, 5, 6. Number 3 also has 3 children namely 7, 8, 9. The on next level containing 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, everyone has 2 children. So basically the number of children keep on alternating according to the parity of each level. If the level is odd then all the numbers will have 2 children otherwise 3 children. You will be given a number n <= 10^18 and you have to print its entire path from root to the number itself.

Example test cases:

Suppose n=2, so path will be 1, 2

Suppose n=6, so path will be 1, 2, 6

Suppose n=16, so path will be 1, 3, 7, 16

Comment: Glad to see that your instructor invents/pokes around unseen/rare problems. Definitely he wants that you explore them yourself to strengthen brain skills. For beginning, determine number of items at every level and index of the leftmost item at that level.

Comment: What exactly is your question for us? Also, this question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it, including a code attempt. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what the problem is, what you expected, what you got, and any error messages.

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

first you need to find the level of n and the (min, max) value of that level

ex: n = 2 => level = 2, min, max = (2, 3)

or if n = 5 => level = 3, min, max = (4, 9)

```
while max < x:
    min = max + 1
    if level % 2 == 1: # odd
    n *= 2
    max += n
    else: # even
    n *= 3
    max += n
    level += 1
```

then we seperate all the numbers in that levels into pairs of 2 or 3 depent on the level we are in (pair = 3 for odd levels and pair = 2 for even) and find the index of the pair which have n

```
        pos = ceil( (x - min + 1) / pair )
```

with these 2 formular we can write a function that return an array (min, max, level, pair)

then we can find the parent of n using:

```
    a = f(n)
    b = f(a[0] - 1)
    parent = b[0] + a[3] - 1
```

here if n = 16 then parent = 7

all you need to do is keep using parent to find other parent of n until you reach 1

Comment: Please do not supply solutions to improper questions.